# Django file sharing system

Tags: python, django, filesystems, system-design

Inspired by a idea of [wetransfer.com](https://wetransfer.com/), i decided to create a similar app with the same functionality. This is a one page app. And i got stuck a bit. The question itself is about system design rather than writting a code.

On the high level the following is happening:

- A user selects files
- Once a file list is formed and an user presses a button to get a link, ajax-request is being initialized with files upload
- Once files upload ended, an unique link is being formed and a client gets it

Easy, but i'm really confused how to make it well from design viewpoint

Let's start from the beginning. How i see that (without too detailed things):

Let's say there will be a temporary folder for forming a final user hierarchy and a final folder for storing a ready-download archive like this:

```
TEMP_USER_FILES = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, "tmp")

FINISHED_USER_FILES = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, "files")
```

Technically i've done something like this:

- There are two inputs (in index.html): for files and folders respectively. JS creates a new empty FormData
- If it gets a file: a file is beeing added into FormData as key: value, where key is a file name and key is a file itself (the same goes for multiple files)
- If it gets a folder: it gets a FileList object, and adds each file from there into our FormData as key: value once again, but where key is *webkitRelativePath* and value is also a file itself
- Then this FormData is beeing sent and Django gets a MultiValueDict with a request.FILES
- Then a new unique UUID is created and a new folder based on our UUID is also created in our temporary folder `tmp/`. So, folder like `tmp/ee03c6fa-072d-47c0-adb5-6bf31f2dbfb4` will refer to a certain user upload
- Then we handle a request.FILES: since keys in request.FILES are either files names or pathes, we are going through this dict with a cycle and creating "on the fly" folders and files there and writting data as the Django official documentation tells:

```
for path in request.FILES:
    dirpath, filename = os.path.split(path)
    
    if dirpath and not os.path.exists(dirpath):
        os.makedirs(dirpath)
        
    with open(path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in request.FILES[path].chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

- And we are forming a final folder with zip-arhive for download (where `temp_path_obj` is a Path object with our temporary path like `tmp/ee03c6fa-072d-47c0-adb5-6bf31f2dbfb4`):

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(FINISHED_USER_FILES, f'{_uuid}.zip'), mode="w") as archive:
    for file_path in temp_path_obj.rglob("*"):
        archive.write(
            file_path,
            arcname=file_path.relative_to(temp_path_obj)
        )
```

- Finally we delete our temporary folder with `shutil.rmtree(temp_path)`

Therefore, a final post-processing will look like this (it's not the pinnacle of creation, but just for instance):

```
class MainView(TemplateResponseMixin, ProcessFormView):
    .......
    .......
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        _uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        Path(os.path.join(TEMP_USER_FILES, _uuid)).mkdir(parents=True)
        temp_path = os.path.join(TEMP_USER_FILES, _uuid)
        temp_path_obj = Path(temp_path)
        os.chdir(temp_path)
        
        for path in request.FILES:
            dirpath, filename = os.path.split(path)
            
            if dirpath and not os.path.exists(dirpath):
                os.makedirs(dirpath)
                
            with open(path, 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in request.FILES[path].chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)

        with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(FINISHED_USER_FILES, f'{_uuid}.zip'), mode="w") as archive:
            for file_path in temp_path_obj.rglob("*"):
                archive.write(
                    file_path,
                    arcname=file_path.relative_to(temp_path_obj)
                )
        
        os.chdir(BASE_DIR)
        shutil.rmtree(temp_path)
        
        return JsonResponse(data={"code": 'success'}, status=200)
```

That's it. Troubles start arising here... It's a bit hard to choose what to do next. According to an initial logic we need to form a link now

Actually, the issues themselves:

- **Where do i need to call link forming from?** Okey, at first sight, it most likely must be an API. Let's say we will have an endpoint like `link/`. Is it better to call it in success function in ajax after uploading or i can call this endpoint out straight from me view(i'm not really sure whether there is such a practice or not), therefore we give our link right away as a response to ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    ......
    ......
    ......
    
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.code == 'success') {
             $.ajax({
                url: 'link/',
                type: 'GET',
                ......
                ......
                ......
            });
        }
    }
});
```

or

```
class MainView(TemplateResponseMixin, ProcessFormView):
    .......
    .......
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        .......
        .......
        link = request.get('link/')
        return JsonResponse(data={"code": "success",
                                  "link": link}, status=200)
```

- **A link implementation itself**. This one is harder in order to decide how it has to look like. The goal is to make the same short url as wetransfer makes (you can try but in general it looks like **t-F9kLieSjcN4N** - it's a random one:) First of all, we are talking about secure url. And there are already so many question and realization options on Stackoverflow about this. So, what is the difference if i create a link just by joining random symbols or if i create a cryptographic signing with salt and some metadata like UUID, timestamp and somesting else but finally they will look the same from the point of brute force, i don't really get it. Meanwhile, it should be short like **t-F9kLieSjcN4N**, is it even possible to make it somehow secure?

```
link1 = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for _ in range(45))
signer = Signer(salt="salt")
link2 = signer.sign("metadata")
print(link1) #GCOGiwyuEaYwAXwvaz7DEfJ27guCnlFUcZNsExdmEFI24
print(link2.split(":")[1]) #yEUVuwNimYYPS2Q-AYO3SYoHSyQrM0WCf9SIdoIClF8
```

- **File Storage**. It is a conclusion rahter than an issue. By listining this all, we will also have to store our data somehow to match a link with a certain correct user data. So, there will be eventually a model with two fields, something similar to this:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    file = models.FilePathField(verbose_name='file', path=FINISHED_USER_FILES, match='\S*\.zip')
    link = models.CharField(verbose_name='link')
```

I don't really have a clue how to make it look secure enough and correct basically. I've just realized that i've always underestimated the issue of system design, both low-level and high-level

Let's discuss